# Amazon IAM permissions list only one bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Currently I have group with a policy that looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449507915000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::artmakeit",
                "arn:aws:s3:::artmakeit/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListAllBuckets",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the IAM user, my client, can access his bucket correctly. But I am wondering if I can only let him see his bucket and not the complete list of my buckets. Is there a way to achieve this? I guess I should change the `ListAllBuckets` permission, but I don't know what to write instead, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users intend to access their buckets via the AWS Management Console, then they **require** the `ListAllBuckets` permission.

It is not possible to 'hide' the complete bucket list when using the console -- either they see them all or none at all.

Access via other methods (eg the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or an API call) does not require that this permission be assigned.